# How to write SMS by dragging fingers

Tags: keyboard, samsung

I was shown that with the messaging app (texting), I can drag my finger along the letters so it writes! How do I do that? I've been looking at my phone forever & I really wanna know.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use an app like [SwiftKey Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey.phone.trial) or [SlideIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dasur.slideit.vt.lite).

**Edit #1:** Take a look @Izzy's comment. It is also possible.

Comment: It could also be that the *Swipe* keyboard comes pre-installed, and simply needs to be enabled in *Settings->Language & Input-> Keyboards & Input Methods*.

Answer (score 2):

There are more keyboards able to do this.

[Swype](http://www.swype.com/) comes preinstalled on Samsung smartphones, but can also be installed from Google Play.

You could also try [SwiftKey Flow](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey) or [Keymonk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keymonk.latin&hl=en).